# JProfiler remote process list empty after selecting container

Tags: jprofiler

I'm using JProfiler 12 and trying to attach via SSH to a remote JVM process in a Docker container. I've followed the instructions here: [https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/whatsnew12.html#:~:text=Attaching%20to%20JVMs%20running](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/whatsnew12.html#:%7E:text=Attaching%20to%20JVMs%20running)

Everything is working well until I have to choose the process. The list is empty. There's no error message.

I can't find any such issue anywhere. I found someone else who had folder permission problems but that cannot be my issue since I'm connecting as root. Even when I chmod folder permissions to 777, it still does nothing.

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I should get:

[image]

[UPDATE 1 Oct 2021]

One problem is I was using a Kubernetes pod [securityContext](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) with readOnlyRootFilesystem, allowPrivilegeEscalation, and dropping some capabilities. When I remove those, I can see the process. But then when I click Open, it fails with this error:

[image]

Which seems to indicate that I was using the wrong user (root). But when I switch to that user, I get this error before I can even choose the container:

[image]

So now I'm stuck one step earlier.

Comment: What is the output of `java -version` for the JVM that you are trying to profile in the Docker container?

Comment: @IngoKegel openjdk version "1.8.0_275"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 3.17.1) (Alpine 8.275.01-r0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.275-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: Can you try to switch to the root user?

Comment: @IngoKegel When I run as the root, then I get the error (see the last dialog screenshot in the question).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a workaround.

It turns out when you use

```
securityContext:
  readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
  capabilities:
    drop:
      - <...capabilities...
```

and

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: <user id>
    runAsGroup: <group id>
    fsGroup: <id>
```

then JProfiler can't connect to your container. So get rid of all this. You can even do it at runtime without having to rebuild your container image by editing your Kubernetes deployment `kubectl edit deployment` to remove these items.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this. JProfiler 13 will have direct support for attaching to Kubernetes, then this should not be an issue anymore.