# JVM list empty after selecting remote docker container (no kubernetes)

Tags: docker, jprofiler

I have the same problem as described in [JProfiler remote process list empty after selecting container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69398612/jprofiler-remote-process-list-empty-after-selecting-container). But because I don't use kubernetes but plain docker, I posted a new question.

JProfiler 12 does not list the available jvm in my docker container. There are no error messages at all, the list is simply empty.

I have multiple docker containers hosting a java process and interestingly the ones that were built with the gradle jib plugin are not shown in the list, the ones that built differrently are shown. Is this just by coincidence?

[UPDATE 27. Oct. 21]
No it does not relate to jib. I built the same spring boot application with a good old Dockerfile and docker build but jprofiler is still not able to find the jvm inside the docker container.

Comment: Lots of improvements for attaching in Docker containers are coming in JProfiler 13. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get an alpha build to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what worked for me is to use a different JDK inside the container. It seems to be the distroless JDK that I used (although another one I used does not work either). Using the eclipse-temurin:11 as base image of the dokcer container fixes the problem for me.